# Do the concepts of intrinsic and extrinsic curvatures imply that all spaces are embedded in a higher dimensional space?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

The concepts of intrinsic and extrinsic curvature seem to imply that all spaces *must* be embedded in a higher dimensional space? What does this imply for physical reality?

Comment: What is your notion of *space*? (given that you talk about curvature, I guess you mean a Riemannian manifold, all of which can be embedded via [Nash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem))

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes you are right; *Riemannian manifold*. I know they *can* be but *must* they be?  *Must we acknowledged higher dimensional spaces?*  This is meant to be a mathematical question but my intent is to apply this question to real spaces (such as Minkowski space-time).

Comment: You  can only define an extrinsic curvature once your slice of space is embedded in a higher dimensional space. But there is no _need_ to do so; a lot of manifold math was developed just so that we could discuss what happens in a space without needing to embed it in a higher space.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): An arbitrary manifold $M$ is embedded in a higher-dimensional space, e.g. $M\times\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically, any topological (metric, or any kind of) space is a sub model of a larger space. That is, you can always find a space of larger dimension that includes the original one. Now, what is the implication of this for physics? that you can always have two theories in which in one, the smaller space is the only thing there is. But there will be also a consistent theory in which that space is embedded inside a higher dimensional space, and there will be no way to distinguish between the two theories. Which one is the correct physical model is not a scientific, but a metaphysical question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How is it a metaphysical question if one theory can provide a more generalized set of information than the other.  You are suggesting that the properties of higher dimensional spaces are arbitrary, artificial and have little bearing on locally measurable objects. For example: before humans realized the Earth's surface was a simply connected space, they could still recognize the existence of gravity which was then found to the result of space-time curvature which requires an understanding of higher dimensional spaces in order to develop a theory.

Comment: Of course you can have a theory where the higher dimensional space is detectable somehow, or has consequences inside our space, etc. But that is not what I meant in my answer. I mean two theories that are equivalent, in the sense that the higher dimensional space has no practical or consequential role. It might or might not be there, but it does not influence the lower dimensional space in any way.

Comment: I suppose you would have to study and understand that higher dimensional space before you could come to the conclusion that there is no practical or consequential role.  Mathematically speaking you can always approach a true euclidean space locally at infinitesimal scales (At that point I agree with you) but in real systems we don't have that luxury and curvature of any higher dimension will exist in principle and it is up for debate how practical or consequential that higher dimension space may be on local objects.